# How could I pair my smart contract with an Upkeep to update my data from API?

Tags: solidity

How could I pair my smart contract with an Upkeep to update my data from API ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: It' would be better if you add a short description about how your smart contract depend on the upkeep or what the upkeep do for your smart contract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need an oracle to fetch data from the API and then a keeper to run it on a particular schedule (or you could set that piece up off-chain).  The problem with relying on upkeep however is that this is one service and if they go down, you go down.  This is a decent sign that it might not be the best case for a smart contract.